# help with accessing nodes at a json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I need your help with the json structure !! (I know it's easy but I cann't figure what the error is).

in this code I'm having a json file that contains a list of items (say restaurants) along with some details for each branch, like the address. In my js file I'm trying to print all the addresses that match specific item id.

I will post a sample of the json file and the js code to access it.

here is the json file:

```
{
"items" : 
[

{
"item_id" :"204","details" :[{"country":"usa","city":"NY", "address":"bla bla bla"},{"country":"usa","city":"NY", "address":"another bla bla bla for the same id"}]
},
{
"item_id" :"234","details" :[{"country":"usa","city":"NY", "address":"another bla bla bla"}]
}

]
}
```

and here is the js code to access that file:

```
.....
success:function(data){
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                if (item.item_id == 204 ) {
            $("#results").append("<hr/>");
                $("#results").append("<span class='result' >" + item.details.address + "</span><br/>");
    }
      });
    }, ....
```

but it doesn't print any thing.

What do you think?

Comment: try `if(item.item_id === "204")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to use $.each in this case, because you have an array of objects i.e. `[{}, {}, {}]` is an array of objects, even though you actually have an object of arrays of objects :p. Each object has a specified index i.e. "item" whereas each array of objects has a default index of 0,1,2 etc.

Also yeah, because you have an array of address object details, you need to access them via `details[0]` or `details[1]`

Check this [example out on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HaYsZ/3/)

```
for(var i =0;i<data.items.length;i++) {

if (data.items[i].item_id == "204" ) {
            $("#results").append("<hr/>");
                $("#results").append("<span class='result' >" + data.items[i].details[0].address + "</span><br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome dear. but the only tiny little problem that it show the first address while I want to print them all one by one. I think I should put a for-loop before the printing line, am I right?

Comment: for (var j=0 ; j< data.items.details.length ; j++) {...} // will that work?

Comment: for (var j=0 ; j< data.items[i].details.length ; j++){
                $("#results").append("<span class='result' >" + data.items[i].details[j].address + "</span><br/>");
}
 // This works fine!!! thx dude :)

Comment: That's exactly right :) No problem. Just FYI, if you have a lot of those address details for each 'items', its much more efficient to do something like: `var details= ''; var results = $('#results'); results.append('<hr />'); for (var j=o;j<data.items[i].details.length;j++) { details += "<span class='result' >" + data.items[i].details[j].address + "</span><br/>" } results.append(details);`. In loops, you want to avoid the number of times you access the selector $('#results'), and 'append' is also computationally expensive, so appending a bigger chunk of text would be better performance wise :)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is valid, so that is not the problem.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item_id": "204",
            "details": [
                {
                    "country": "usa",
                    "city": "NY",
                    "address": "bla bla bla"
                },
                {
                    "country": "usa",
                    "city": "NY",
                    "address": "another bla bla bla for the same id"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "item_id": "234",
            "details": [
                {
                    "country": "usa",
                    "city": "NY",
                    "address": "another bla bla bla"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can view a modified example at: http://jsfiddle.net/wKDUu/.  The code below will loop through the details to accomodate a more dynamic approach.

```
success:function(data){ 
    var di = data.items;     
    for(var i=0;i<di.length;i++){ 
        var ii = di[i]; 
        if (ii.item_id == 204 ) {              
            $("#results").append("<hr/>"); 
            for(var a=0;a<ii.details.length;a++){ 
                $("#results").append("<span class='result' >" + ii.details[a].address + "</span><br/>"); 
            } 
        }        
    }    
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since item.details is an array, you need to get it via `item.details[0].address`